# Dock for macbook that supports 2xTB3 displays, charging, and at last one USB-A?

Tags: thunderbolt, dock, thunderbolt-display

I'm trying to determine what type of dock I should get for my MacBook, but the problem I'm facing is that most TB3 docks I'm finding only support HDMI or DP monitors.

I'm trying to find a dock, or some kind of adapter, that will support the following:

- Two 4K 60hz monitors that connect over TB3 (not HDMI, or DP)
- Charging over TB3 (or with a built in power cable)
- At least 1 USB-3 port so that I can plug by USB hub into it.
- Plugs into my MacBook as either a single cable or a single unit that takes up two TB3 ports, so long as it's a single unit I can plug in.

My goal is to have only one cable plugged into my Mac Book. I'm really trying to avoid having to buy a dock that supports HDMI or DP for display because that would mean I'd also have to replace my monitor cables with HDMI or DP cables on top of buying a dock.

I've already seen at least one similar question:

- [Is there a 1 cable solution to connect 2 monitors in extended mode and charge a MacBook 15" at the same time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338325/is-there-a-1-cable-solution-to-connect-2-monitors-in-extended-mode-and-charge-a)

But the solution there is a dock that works with HDMI displays.

Is there a type of dock that would support this? I'm not necessarily asking for a specific product. I just want to know what type of dock would achieve this.

The closest product I've found so far is [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09LV3LRTQ). But it only supports the two monitors and not charging on the same device (from what I can tell)

---

I'm new to this forum, so if this question doesn't aline with the guidelines for this community I'll be happy to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbolt 3 docks that I have seen have one TB3 connection for your computer (powered) and one TB3 port for devises as well as a mixture of other ports.

If your displays are TB3 you should be able to daisy chain them off the singe TB3 port. Otherwise, you would be best to revise one of the displays to connect via HDMI or DP.

This would provide a single cable to your computer solution.

Examples of TB3 Powered Docks:

- [CalDigit TS3 Plus](https://www.caldigit.com/ts3-plus/)
- [OWC 14-Point Thunderbolt 3 Dock](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/thunderbolt-3-dock-14-port)

Comment: My monitors have HDMI out. The cables I have go from HDMI to TB3. I do this so that I can plug them into my Mac Mini, and if possible, I'd like to use the same cables  for my MacBook dock. That's the reason I want to avoid buying new cables.

Comment: You mean they go from HDMI to mDP-over-USBC.  Get two regular DP-DP cables and use something like the CalDigit USB-C Pro Dock.  NOT the HDMI one.